# Why is 1413 µS/cm specifically the "standard" conductivity standard?

Tags: conductivity, history-of-chemistry

I'm doing some work on conductivity sensor calibration, and noticed that all the conductivity standard suppliers offer a 1413 µS/cm standard solution. Why is this oddly specific value the "standard"?

Comment: It may be conductivity of some round concentration of KCl, that is usually used.

Comment: There are several values for different calibration levels. 1413 µS/cm is the value for 0.01 mol/l KCl(aq), and 12880 μS/cm is for 0.1 mol/l KCl(aq), both at 25 °C. Don't have time to find a decent reference and post a proper answer, maybe someone else could catch up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, conductivity is the reciprocal of the resistance so in essence you are just measuring the resistance of a solution. Making a 0.01 M solution of KCl (aq) is straightforward and the eleectrical resistance (aka conductivity) can be measured very accurately. This is why a 0.01 M KCl conductivity standard has an odd value of 1413 µS/cm. This NIST document fully explains the theory behind conductivity measurements and how to make primary standards.
https://www.nist.gov/system/files/documents/srm/260-142-2ndVersion.pdf